# How can I get the :regexp property for abbrev to work?

Tags: abbrev

I have a local abbrev table set up in a file. I have an abbrev that has the "+" character. By default, abbrev will not expand this abbrev because it sees "+" as a word boundary.

The [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Abbrev-Table-Properties.html) say this can be resolved with the `:regexp` property.

I tried it out. Consider this setup:

```
(set-local-abbrevs '(
             ("mse" "mean square error" nil)
             ("wlog" "without loss of generality" nil)
             ("++" "\\+" nil)
             ))

(defvar my-abbrev-regexp
  "\\([[:word:]]+\\)"
  ;; "\\([0-9A-Za-z._-]+\\)"
  "")

(abbrev-table-put local-abbrev-table :regexp  my-abbrev-regexp)
(abbrev-mode)
```

Let's for a minute forget the abbrev with the "+" character and try to expand "wlog". If I comment out the `abbrev-table-put` line, it expands it just fine when I press SPC. If I uncomment it, then I cannot get "wlog" to expand. I tried both regular expressions shown, both with and without the "+" quantifier.

I also tried the suggested solution [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33527/regexp-only-matching-one-character-when-using-abbreviations), adding the "<" character to the regexp, and it still doesn't expand.

Edit: Apparently `set-local-abbrevs` is a custom function I had in my config, taken from the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode). It creates a local abbrev table. Below is the definition.

```
(defun set-local-abbrevs (abbrevs)
    "Add ABBREVS to `local-abbrev-table' and make it buffer local.
     ABBREVS should be a list of abbrevs as passed to `define-abbrev-table'.
     The `local-abbrev-table' will be replaced by a copy with the new 
     abbrevs added, so that it is not the same as the abbrev table used
     in other buffers with the same `major-mode'."
    (let* ((bufname (buffer-name))
           (prefix (substring (md5 bufname) 0 (length bufname)))
           (tblsym (intern (concat prefix "-abbrev-table"))))
      (set tblsym (copy-abbrev-table local-abbrev-table))
      (dolist (abbrev abbrevs)
          (define-abbrev (eval tblsym)
            (car abbrev)
            (cadr abbrev)
            (caddr abbrev)))
    (setq-local local-abbrev-table (eval tblsym))))
```

I'll examine the definition in detail later, but a quick glance isn't finding an obvious cause for my problems.

Update: OK, Tyler's solution works if I put the string verbatim in `abbrev-table-put`, but not if I put it in the `my-abbrev-regexp` variable. Likely the number of backslashes?

Now that I have "wlog" working, I still can't get ++ to expand.My regexp is `\\<\\([+[:word:]]+\\)`. Ideas?

Comment: What is `set-local-abbrevs`? It does not seem to be defined in my Emacs.

Comment: Good catch. Apparently I got it from the Emacs Wiki. I've updated the question with the details.

Comment: Maybe not a bug: @Tyler's answer in the linked question fingers just this problem and modifies the regexp to do a greedy match supposedly - but I haven't tried it out to make sure that it works yet.

Comment: @Tyler's answer works fine: it extends the match to the beginning of the word. So the simple examples (`mse`, `wlog`) work fine. Now to extend it...

Comment: The backward search in `abbrev--before-point` `(looking-back re (line-beginning-position))` is non-greedy, so it will stop e.g. at the `g` of `wlog` instead of consuming as much as possible (i.e. all of `wlog`). You can test by changing that line to add a `t` as a third argument which makes the search greedy.  I thought this was a bug at first, but as the previous comments make clear, I think you have to specify the regexp as in @Tyler's answer to the linked question.

Comment: OK, I got Tyler's solution working if I put the string in the function rather than in a variable. I, however, cannot get my desired ++ abbrev to work. Ideas why?

Comment: The variable works fine but you have to `setq`: `defvar` sets the default value but once the variable has a value, `defvar` will not change it. No progress on the `+` stuff: haven't had the time.